# How to pronounce al- at the start of a word?

Tags: pronunciation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sounds of the letter a](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7998/sounds-of-the-letter-a)

I was wondering if there is a general pronunciation rule for how to pronounce A and L when they start the word. I noticed words
Also
Almost
Always
Alright
Almighty
Already
Although.. etc.
That is, al- is followed by a consonant, A is pronounced more like O.

where as in words where L is followed by a vowel, A is pronounced more like A, not O. For example:
Alone
Alike
Along
Aluminium
etc.

then I thought of 'Ale' where its pronounced even differently. or the word Ally (allies) where L is followed by a consonant but pronounced as if followed by a vowel.

My confusion is then between /ɔl/ and /el/ Is there a rule and what is it?

Comment: Questions about pronunciation are difficult to answer, partly because pronunciation is so variable. For example, do you have in mind British or American English? And it's also very difficult to show how words are pronounced without using phonemic symbols.

Comment: i was not aware of differences of pronunciation in American/British with the al- prefix. From my experience it's pretty universal (am i wrong?)

My question is pretty narrow and precise. the 'possible duplicate' question does not answer my question, and it is even stranger that mine gets closed, but the question about terminal -al pronunciation does not. Well, let us look for answers elsewhere where moderators are more sensible :)

Comment: Accents for words like *Always* differ within the US, and are different from BrE too. And, indeed, a Scotsman saying *Always* would be different from a southern-Englishman.

Comment: However when i heard my girlfriend pronouncing 'also' as /el/ I shivered. Neither an Alabaman nor a Scotsman would pronounce it that way, to the best of my knowledge after my travels :)

but then am I to understand, there is no specific rule?

Comment: For example, the American pronunciation of ‘always’ can begin with /ɔl/ or /ɑl/. In British English, it’s /ɔːl/. See the problem?

Comment: Thank you Barrie - but Alas! (Alas? thats even stranger al-).
These pronunciations are still defined by something then, if you made them as finite as that. So there must be some rule defining it? So that students would not pronounce Also as /el-/.

 I couldn't find it in the '..for dummies' series :)

I was probably most interested in the precise pronunciation for British (Queens) English, or Oxridge english if you like, simply because I spent many years in England. But really 'a rule' would be appreciated. any :)

Comment: re your original post, gendalfas - I've not checked, but, to my ear, 'pronounced even differently' tries to extract a meaning from _even_ even it doesn't allow: _differently (yet) again_ or _in yet another way_ are certainly OK.

Comment: Oh, and if you want a really quirky one, _almond_ can be pronounced _ol_ - mənd, _ahl_ - mənd or _ah_ - mənd. (I tried, Barrie.)

Comment: There is no rule, except that unstressed ‘a’ will tend to become /ə/ (see RegDwighт’s rule 8 in the link at top). English pronunciation has changed in various directions since its spelling was (sort of) fixed in the 14th century; we’ve borrowed all sorts of words, with their spellings, which don’t follow English models; and depending on when those words came into the language, their pronunciations have changed in different directions, too — often different directions in different places. There’s just too much historical contingency to look for ‘rules’ with more than statistical significance.